# Sort NSArray Alphabetically

Tags: nsarray

I wrote a code that sorts a NSArray alphabetically by last name. I can't figure how to make it follow all the way to the first name. There is strLName (which is the Last Name) and strFName (which is the first name.

I need it to look like this (as an example):

Steve Jackson
Tim Jackson
Allen Jones
Diane Jones

Currently it does this:

Tim Jackson
Steve Jackson
Diane Jackson
Allen Jackson

Here is my code so far:

```
   {
    [super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g", @"h", @"i", @"j", @"k", @"l", @"m", @"n", @"o", @"p", @"q", @"r", @"s", @"t", @"u", @"v", @"w", @"x", @"y", nil];

mArrSearched = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].arrGuests.count; i++) 

 {  President *pres = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].arrGuests objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *strLName = pres.strLName;

    NSString *strAlpha = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [strLName characterAtIndex:0]];

    NSString *str = [arr objectAtIndex:self.nIdx-1];

    NSLog(@"LastName=%@, Alpha=%@, selectedStr=%@", strLName, strAlpha, str);

    if ([strAlpha isEqualToString:[str uppercaseString]] || [strAlpha isEqualToString:str]) 
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i], @"Index", strLName, @"Name", nil];

        [mArrSearched addObject:dict];
    }
}
[self sortByAlpha];

[tblView reloadData];
}


- (void) sortByAlpha {

NSSortDescriptor * frequencyDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];

id obj;

if (mArrSearched.count > 0) 
{
    NSEnumerator * enumerator = [mArrSearched objectEnumerator];

    while ((obj = [enumerator nextObject])) NSLog(@"%@", obj);

    NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frequencyDescriptor, nil];

    NSArray * sortedArray = [mArrSearched sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

    NSLog(@"\nSorted ...");

    enumerator = [sortedArray objectEnumerator];

    while ((obj = [enumerator nextObject])) NSLog(@"%@", obj);

    NSLog(@"%d", [[[mArrSearched objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Name"] intValue]);

    mArrSearched = [sortedArray mutableCopy];

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure how to make it follow all the way to the first name.

You've almost got the answer right in your code:

```
NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frequencyDescriptor, nil];
NSArray * sortedArray = [mArrSearched sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

The point you're missing is that you can add more than one sort descriptor to the array `descriptors`, and they'll be applied in order until the sort order of two items can be determined. So, if the first sort descriptor says two items match, the second descriptor is used, and so on. NSArray's documentation page says:

> The first descriptor specifies the primary key path to be used in
>   sorting the receiving array’s contents. Any subsequent descriptors are
>   used to further refine sorting of objects with duplicate values. See
>   NSSortDescriptor for additional information.